# How do I make an annotation based event system?

Tags: java, events, annotations, eventhandler

Well I already made one but I don't know if it's the best tbh. Can anyone write me a good tutorial? I made this one with a tutorial and I understood 90% of it but 10% of off and it seems this aint the best way to do it.

EventManager.java

public class EventManager {

```
private static List<Listener> registered = new ArrayList<Listener>();

public static void register(Listener listener) {
    if (!registered.contains(listener)) {
        registered.add(listener);
    }
}

public static void unregister(Listener listener) {
    if (registered.contains(listener)) {
        registered.remove(listener);
    }
}

public static List<Listener> getRegistered() {
    return registered;
}

public static void callEvent(final Event event) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            call(event);
        }
    }.start();
}

private static void call(final Event event) {
    for (Listener registered : getRegistered()) {
        Method[] methods = registered.getClass().getMethods();

        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            EventHandler eventHandler = methods[i].getAnnotation(EventHandler.class);
            if (eventHandler != null) {
                Class<?>[] methodParams = methods[i].getParameterTypes();

                if (methodParams.length < 1) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!event.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(methodParams[0].getSimpleName())) {
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    methods[i].invoke(registered.getClass().newInstance(), event);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    System.err.println(exception);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

EventHandler.java

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface EventHandler {

}
```

and Event.java and Listener.java are blank interfaces.

Comment: Seems fine, what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: I feel like the way i'm doing it can be way better tbh.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? If your intent is to create an event handler based on annotations, you should implement it is you did, by going over the methods of the class and checking which one is annotated with the specific annotation of the event being handled. You could add some caching, so that secondary handling of the same class would not have to check the methods anymore (if no dynamic class loading is done in your system). You could also consider doing all the checking of which methods to call during the registration of the listeners rather than during event handling.

Comment: Ok one thing though, is Listener really needed? Couldn't I just use Class<?> to register and register like this EventManager.register(test.class); would listener be useful or just not needed? Optimization wise.

Comment: It doesn't have to implement a specific interface. I'm not sure that it would be an improvement to remove it though. Consider that if the register method accepts instances of any class, your API becomes more obscure, as there no way of knowing which type of class should be registered. One way to improve this is to allow only classes annotated with a special `@listener`  annotation to register.

Comment: One more thing, if you can use a DI framework (e.g. Spring, Guice, CDI), you can inject the classes instead of registering them. That would certainly make you code more dynamic.